# Tensorflow: Model not loading

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, image-recognition

I am new to tf and i am building an image classifier.

The problem is that the predicted probabilities by using function `sess.run()` are not changing even if the input image is changed.

I have built the model and in the code given below, I am loading it and trying to predict an image.

```
def predict():
    train = data.train
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    with tf.Session() as sess:

        new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('~/trained-model.ckpt.meta')

        new_saver.restore(sess, '~/trained-model.ckpt')
        print(tf.get_default_graph().get_name_scope())
        #contains the softmax output of last_layer
        y_pred = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('y_pred:0')
        X = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('X:0')

        final = imageprepare('tshirts.png')
        final = np.asarray(final) 
        final = np.reshape(final,[784,1]


        output_label = sess.run(y_pred, feed_dict={X: final}) 

        print(output_label)
```

The `output_label` is not changing even if I change the input image (tshirts.png)

Whole code is https://codeshare.io/2jO4oR Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might need to do some debugging (it is fairly unlikely anybody can tell you the reason from the info provided). Do you get good results when you train the model (presumably you evaluate it on some images)? Are your probabilities exactly the same or just the label/class is the same? Take a look at your graph in TensorBoard. Try your workflow on some trivial model. Use tfdbg if simpler approaches don't work.